# Why do operators not work in C++-CLI?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build, c++-cli, compare, operators

According to microsoft, the operators in C++ are the same in visual studio C++ 2010
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x04xhy0h.aspx
However, look at the following builds:

```
int^ number = 32;

if (number < 100)
    MessageBox::Show("The number is not greater than 100");
```

Build failed
'<' : 'System::Int32 ^' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

```
if (number <= 100)
    MessageBox::Show("The number is not greater than 100");
```

Build failed
'<=' : 'System::Int32 ^' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

```
if (number == 32)
    MessageBox::Show("The is equal to 32");
```

Build successful... However the message is not displayed.

```
if (number = 32)
    MessageBox::Show("The is equal to 32");
```

Build successful.. The message is displayed. (Why? The operator of the equality is ==)

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int^` declares a [handle to an object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yk97tc08.aspx). Whenever you reference `number` directly, you're actually referencing a boxed integer (somewhat equivalent to `(object)32` in C#).

In addition, handles to objects don't define the `<` or `<=` (or `>` or `>=`) operators when comparing to an integer literal. The reason for that can be deducted from the following:

They do, however define an `==` operator. But in order to compare, the literal value you're comparing to will be implicitly boxed, making the comparison (somewhat) equivalent to this C# code:

```
object number = 32;
if (number == (object)32)
    MessageBox.Show("The number is equal to 32");
```

That comparison will check if the references are the same. Which they aren't - they're two different objects. Hence:

```
int^ number = 32;
if (number == 32)
    MessageBox::Show("The number is equal to 32"); // isn't displayed
```

... and since you're comparing references rather than values, `>`, `>=`, `<=`, `<` would make little sense.

In your last case, you're *assigning* `32` to `number`, then checking if the result of that expression (which is itself 32) is different from 0 - it is, so the message is displayed. That's what `if` does in C++ (and C) - in C#, `number = 32` does have the result `32`, but you'd get a compiler error due to the `if` requiring a boolean value.

"Solution": Dereference the `int^`:

```
if (*number == 32)
    MessageBox::Show("The number is equal to 32");
```

... or simply use `int`:

```
int number = 32;
```

**EDIT:** Rewrote based on Ben Voigt's more correct explanation.

Comment: .net does define operators for handles... for reference types. But this is a value type,and there's no reason at all to make a handle to it.

Comment: And no it isn't comparing an address to 32... The 32 gets boxed, then the two boxed ints are checked for reference identity, which will always be false.

Comment: @BenVoigt - interesting... While I know C++ and .NET, I admit I'm not exactly well versed in C++/CLI - so I actually did test the above claim, and comparing `number` to the integer address as found by inspection (e.g. `number == 0x1234abcd`) did appear to yield `true`. Must have made some oversight.

Comment: How did you do that, in compiled code or in the debugger?  If in compiled code, what was the type of the variable used for the RHS (where you placed the address you observed)?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Modified the contents of `value` in `if (number == value)` in the debugger to match the address of `number`. But can't reproduce when trying again, so I *did* make some oversight at the time. Since the answer is accepted, I've edited it to (hopefully) make it more accurate.